# ld: framework not found Base64

Tags: xcode, react-native

In 02/08/2022
I am trying to make an IPA file in my **React Native** project.
I can build it and test in a ios simulator, or build on my external device, but when I try to archive, I am getting this error:

```
ld: framework not found Base64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

My configuration is:

"react": "16.9.0" 
"react-native": "0.61.3"

Xcode version: 13.4.1

In 04/08/2022 
I understood that this lib is used with my react-native-code-push library and testing, I removed the code push from package.json and pod install on my iOS. Result? The error changed to:

```
ld: framework not found FBLPromises
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I think this is related to the pods not installing properly the node_modules library

Comment: Is it m1 chip macbook pro ?

Comment: no, it isnt... i3